# How to solve too many @Value in Spring Boot service

Tags: spring-boot

I build `Spring Boot` service and have `BookService` with almost 15 different `@Value` fields. They all are constants and can be shared into other places into application. Some of them relate to Amazon access, some to `Redis` keys.

Is there any way to reduce amount of values consumed from `application.properties`? Is it normal industry practice to have anything like this? Can I use any other approach for this?

`BookService.java` snippet:

```
@Service
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    private StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @Value("${redis.orders.timestampKey}")
    private String redisOrdersTimestampKey;

    @Value("${redis.orders.retrunsKey}")
    private String redisOrdersReturnsKey;

    @Value("${redis.orders.quantityKey}")
    private String redisOrdersQuantityKey;

    ...
}
```

My main concern that design I built is far away from industry best-practices and may be hard to work in the future.

Comment: If your service has so many properties, the service is doing too much and most likely needs to be split.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use some kind of spring's `ConfigurationProperties`. [Here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) you can find more.

this should work for you:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "redis")
public class RedisProperties {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private Order orders;

    // ..getters and setters


    public static class Order{

        private String timestampKey;
        private String retrunsKey;
        private String quantityKey;

        // ..getters and setters
    }
}
```

then add this dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

and create some configuration like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(RedisProperties.class)
public class SomeConfiguration {
}
```

you can then use `RedisProperties` like standard spring bean and inject it where you need.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties

You create a properties class and autowire it in your service. You can also validate your properties. Your class could look as below (note: this is with `Lombok`):

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "redis.orders")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Validated
public class RedisOrderProperties {

    @NotEmpty
    private String redisOrdersTimestampKey;

    @NotEmpty
    private String redisOrdersReturnsKey;

    @NotEmpty
    private String redisOrdersQuantityKey;

}
```

Autowire it in your service as follows (note: constructor injection should be favoured over field injection):

```java
@Service
public class BookService {

    private final RedisOrderProperties redisOrderProperties;
    private final StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public BookService(RedisOrderProperties redisOrderProperties, StringRedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
        this.redisOrderProperties = redisOrderProperties;
        this.redisTemplate = redisTemplate;
    }

}
```